# How to have a button with the same width as appbar?

Tags: flutter

**Summary:** 
Currently i have this result:
[image]

My goal is to have this result (all elements are aligned):
[image]

**Explanation:** 
I defined a standard appBar, FlatButton and textField. I would like to have all elements same width and aligned vertically.
Default appBar and TextField have same width but not my button. So, how to have a button with the same width as other elements ?

**Code:**

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

/// Styles
class Homepage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Test", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      ),

      body: Stack(children: <Widget>[
        new Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,

          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              child: Center(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 50,
                    ),

                     new ButtonTheme(
                      //minWidth: 300,
                      child: FlatButton(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      child: Text('Play', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white)),
                      onPressed: () {
                        // Perform some action
                      },
                    ),

                ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 50,
                    ),
                    new ListTile(
                      leading: const Icon(Icons.person),
                      title: new TextField(
                        decoration: new InputDecoration(
                          hintText: "Name Player 1",
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),                    
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: A good way to discover what Widget is using some space with padding/margin/etc., is to enable "Show debug paint" in [Flutter Inspector](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/inspector)

Answer (score 0):

Use a `SizedBox` with infinite width to make your `FlatButton` fill the horizontal space, then wrap it in a `Padding` (`AppBar` padding is 16):

```dart
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0, horizontal: 16),
  child: SizedBox(
    width: double.infinity,
    child: FlatButton(
      onPressed: null,
      child: Text('Play'),
    ),
  ),
);
```